# regex help needed for text block matching - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to help someone with an extension for VS Code, but we're having some difficulty when it comes to matching on a feature of the language that we use called text blocks.

Text blocks begin with an @ symbol followed immediately by a tag (that could comprise any `\w` character). The text block ends with the same tag (with no decoration) on a blank line. The text in between can comprise any regular ascii character. For example:

```
string text = @text
```

This is a text block and this is a feature that
can allow you to enter large amounts of text
and assign them to a variable. The "tag" that is used
is up to the developer and can be anything.

Even new lines like the above
Or lines like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
text
;

string text2 = @text
```

And of course, you could have
multiple of these. :/
text
;

Any help would be appreciated and thank you so much in advance for taking a look.

Comment: Sounds like you need a parser, rather than regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
@(\w+)\r?\n(?:[ -~]*\r?\n)*?\1$
```

- `@` Match literally
- `(\w+)\r?\n` Capture 1+ word characters in **group 1** followed by a newline
- `(?:[ -~]*\r?\n)*?` Repeat as least as possible times any ASCII char followed by a newline
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1 (match the closing tag with the same word)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vniHyg/1)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. Your explanation was definitely helpful as well.